# Delivery from multiplexed channels in Netty 5

Tags: java, netty, spdy

Since a Netty Channel uses a single thread for both inbound and outbound processing, I'm curious to know the recommended practice for delivery of inbound data when using a multiplexed protocol, such as SPDY.  A few options that come to mind:

1) Deliver data for all streams to the application (i.e. non-channel code) using the channel thread.  In this case, delivery does not incur an extra context switch. The application will have to know to defer any heavy lifting onto its own threads in order to be a "good consumer".  If it doesn't, it could effectively block any writes on the channel from occurring for some time (since both read and write use the same thread).

2) Deliver using a separate Executor (optionally with thread affinity per stream). In this case, we incur the context-switch early on.  An application that blocks the delivery thread will not block Netty's pipeline. The downside of this is that the application logic in some (possibly many) cases may be fairly light-weight and might not warrant the context switch.

3) Introduce a multi-threaded EventLoop with thread affinity per stream. This, however, seems to violate the current assumption that a Channel be single-threaded.  I'm not sure that this is viable. Maybe someone with more knowledge of the Netty internals can confirm?

Does anyone know of other considerations or have additional options that I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is to put the "application logic" (that would block the io thread) into an extra ChannelHandler and add it to the ChannelPipeline with a custom EventExecutorGroup. This way the processing is moved from the EventLoop to the EventExecutor that is provided out of the EventExecutorGroup.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  So it seems that this would essentially be a variant of #2.  Am I right and thinking that #3 would simply not work in Netty 5.x?